# Conectar no banco oracle por linha de comando após instalação

Tags: oracle

Instalei o banco Oracle, mas não me lembro como eu me conecto no prompt do banco. Acho que é System connect "password". Alguém me corrige, favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No terminal oracle digita-se:

```
CONNECT SYSTEM/root
```

root é a senha definida na instalação.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONNECT system/mypassword@mydbserver.mydomain.com
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/connecting.htm

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85890)

Comment: O comando para conectar esta aí.

Answer (score -1):

Uma coisa que pode experimentar, é se for o mesmo utilizador a fazer a instalação, 
experimente fazer:

```
 conn / as sysdba
```